# Reason for Interrupted attempting lock

Tags: hibernate, jboss, transactions

My code is behaving randomly.I am using Hibernate as ORM and JBoss6 as app server. I get the below exception randomly.I am not able to figure out the reason for this.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Interrupted attempting lock: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@5458ca9
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.tryLock(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:402)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.lock(WrappedConnection.java:146)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:394)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:116) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2412) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    ... 31 more
12:48:50,276 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1) org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
12:48:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:679)
12:48:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892)
12:48:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782)
12:48:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
12:48:50,277 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:147)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at com.verisk.dep.common.aspect.DaoInterceptor.invoke(DaoInterceptor.java:38)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at $Proxy136.userRegistration(Unknown Source)
12:48:50,278 ERROR [stderr] (pool-6-thread-1)   at
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

In my case, my programm had a ThreadPool with some tasks that were scheduled at a fixed rate with the method java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate.

And at some given situations, when i had to stop and remove some of this tasks, i used the method java.util.concurrent.Future.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) with the mayInterruptIfRunning set to true.

This caused the software to throw the "java.sql.SQLException: Interrupted attempting lock" exception. I think it's because the programm cancels the task interrupting the thread and it was running a database operation or something similar.

So, I changed the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter to false and I force the programm to wait while the task had not been finished and cancelled.

Here is an example of the solution:

```
List<ScheduledFuture> tasks = new ArrayList<ScheduledFuture>();
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);

tasks.add(threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(yourRunnableTask, 0L, 60000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

...

for(int i=0; i<tasks.size(); i++)
{
    ScheduledFuture task = tasks.get(i);
    task.cancel(false);

    int retrys = 0;

    while(!task.isCancelled() && retrys < 3)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }

        retrys++
    }

    if(task.isCancelled())
    {
        // This is not actually neccesary (only a good practice)
        task.cancel();
        threadPool.remove(task);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue I was running into.  We had a scheduled thread that was running, but once we interrupted it and tried to connect to the database to do some final updates the JDBC driver called class ReentrantLock to obtain a lock, but that call checks if the current thread is interrupted, and if it IS it throws the InterruptedException which causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that I was getting like 300+ objects from DB, then mapping them and sending back to FE, this all took around 1.5sec, but I had a `@Timeout` annotation on the controller set to 500ms, so after that time it has thrown the error, but managed to report the data back to FE correctly, so it was pure luck to notice the error